# Increment ID during writing to the file (C#, CSV)

Tags: c#, csv, streaming, increment

I'm reading XLS file and passing number (curren row from excel = **currow**) to method which is creating object inside new csv file:

```
public class Importer
...
IList<NewDataObj> n_obj = new List<NewDataObj>();    
foreach (var item in data.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Field<string>("MyID") == ImportID)){             

         n_obj.Add(new NewDataObj(item, ID, currow));
         currow++;}
....
```

**Method to create new DataObj:**

```
public class NewDataObj{
....
 public static string_1  = "\"{3}\";\"NEW_OBJECT\";\"TEST\"{5}\";
 public static string_2  = "\"{3}\";\"NEW OBJECT\";\"TEST_A2\"{5}\";
 public double DataID { get; set; }
.....
 public NewDataObj(DataRow item, string newID, int currow){
  ....
  ID = string.Format("{{ABC_TEST_{0:000}}}", currow);
  AddtoFile_A();
  //AddtoFile_A2();
 }

 public void AddtoFile_A(){
  using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("testX.csv"))
   {
    w.WriteLine(string.Format(string_1, DataID, ID, Environment.NewLine));
   }
 }
}
```

This is working ok, but now I had to add AddtoFile_A2 method.

```
public void AddtoFile_A2(){
  using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("testX.csv"))
 {
 w.WriteLine(string.Format(string_2, DataID, ID, Environment.NewLine));
 }
}
```

And AddtoFile_A2 is using also the same currow. For me, when AddtoFile_A or AddtoFile_A2 is executed then ID should be always increase by 1.

How to do that? Maybe my AddtoFile method should return value to Importer class?

Comment: You don't seem to increase currow anywhere in the code posted and also you need to recreate the ID string

Comment: @Steve...class Importer currow++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got answer from my colleague - should be passed as `ref int currow`:

```
public class Importer
...
IList<NewDataObj> n_obj = new List<NewDataObj>();    
foreach (var item in data.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Field<string>("MyID") == ImportID)){             

         n_obj.Add(new NewDataObj(item, ID, ref currow));//one change
         currow++;}
....
```

And into method:

```
public class NewDataObj{
.....
 public NewDataObj(DataRow item, string newID, ref int currow){ //second changes
  ....
  ID = string.Format("{{ABC_TEST_{0:000}}}", currow);
  AddtoFile_A();

  currow++; //next changes
  ID = string.Format("{{ABC_TEST_{0:000}}}", currow); //new id
  AddtoFile_A2();
 }
```

Just tested and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) instead of writing csv by hands.

```
var data = new[] {
    new BuisnessObject{ Id=1, Name="FOO" },
    new BuisnessObject{ Id=2, Name="BAR" }
};

if (data.Any())
{
    // RowNumber=index or RowNumber=index+1 
    var ouputs = data.Select(
                        (item, index) => 
                        new OuputType {
                           Id=item.Id,
                           Name=item.Name,
                           RowNumber=index 
                        }
                    );

    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter($"OuputFileName.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
        csv.WriteHeader<OuputType>();
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteRecords(ouputs);
    }
}

public sealed class BuisnessObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class OuputType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<OuputType>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.RowNumber);
    }
}
```

You can order the column by moving around the  map in TestMap Class. Or change the name using `.Name("PrettyName")`

Comment: I choose to have a select to map instead of using mapper directly for a simple exemple like like so if you have a more complex map between buizness and Csv object you can add it in the select. Like a select many or Something like this. It will be easier to use the old mapping you have than Learning how to do it with a new lib .

Comment: if Im using **SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]** to get all data from my excel, it will be working as well?

Comment: I'm confused.
Here my variable `data` is kinda a representation of the excel data. 
It's not the same as the data you show in your question. 
But to answer the question, Yes.
Select all the line from your excel , `data.AsEnumerable()`.
Filter the one you want, `.Where(o => o.Field<string>("MyID") == ImportID`.
This part is exactly what you have.

Comment: Now comes the projection, The transphormation an object into a new form that often consists only of those properties that will be subsequently used._
`.Select(x=> new MyClass(){
  Property1 = (string)x.Field<string>("ColumnName1"),
  Property1 = (int)x.Field<int>("ColumnName2"),
  Property1 = (bool)x.Field<bool>("ColumnName3"),    
})`.

Comment: @4est, As I'm not sure I understood the question I try to over clarify. I will be around for 2-3 hours fell free to ask any

Comment: thank you for update and complex explanation, I will try to rebuild my app in free time, once again thank you

Comment: No problemo thats what StackOverflow is about ^^